# $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy classes of maps from and to $\mathbb{G}_m^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand relatively simple examples of calculations in $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy theory to build intuition.

For example, if $S$ is a scheme over a field $k$, what is the set $[\mathbb{G}_m, S]_{\mathbb{A}^1}$ of $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy classes of morphisms from $\mathbb{G}_m$ to $S$ over $k$? $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the multiplicative group.

How does this generalize to $\mathbb{G}_m^n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Also dually, what are $[S, \mathbb{G}_m^n]_{\mathbb{A}^1}$?

Comment: This is not an elementary question. It is easier if you replace the multiplicative group by the projective line. For instance, there is a nice and rather explicit motivic version of the degree, as in this paper of Cazanave: http://www.numdam.org/item/ASENS_2012_4_45_4_511_0/

Comment: @Denis-CharlesCisinski, I too had in mind to think of [,] as a kind of loop space and pointed-maps version of $[,]_{\mathbb{A}^1}$ as a kind of fundamental group. Does that makes some sense? Using $\mathbb{G}_m^n$, or for that matter $\mathbb{P}^n$, as probe spaces to explore the topology of $S$ just as one does with spheres $S^n$ in classical homotopy theory seems like a fruitful idea. Would love your comments on it.